# Restart PostgreSQL Remotely

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Can I remotely restart a PostgreSQL server throught PGAdmin ? The user I currently is the administrative privileges.

Regards,

Dino

Comment: Why do you want to restart?  Is there some less drastic measure you can take to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is such possibility. At best you can **reload** connected PostgreSQL server using [`pg_reload_conf()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE) function:

> pg_reload_conf sends a SIGHUP signal
>   to the server, causing configuration
>   files to be reloaded by all server
>   processes.

Command:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

You can also install [adminpack contrib module](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/extend.html) and reload server using Tools menu.

**EDIT:**

According to pgAdmin [documentation](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect.html):

> If pgAdmin is running on a Windows
>   machine, it can control the postmaster
>   service if you have enough access
>   rights. Enter the name of the service.
>   In case of a **remote server**, it must be
>   prepended by the machine name (e.g.
>   PSE1\pgsql-8.0). pgAdmin will
>   automatically discover services
>   running on your local machine.
>
> If pgAdmin is running on a Unix
>   machine, it can control processes
>   running on the local machine if you
>   have enough access rights. Enter a
>   full path and needed options to access
>   the pg_ctl program. When executing
>   service control functions, pgAdmin
>   will append status/start/stop keywords
>   to this. Example: sudo
>   /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D
>   /data/pgsql

You can try use Start Service/Stop Service options (in Tools menu) to restart remote server.

Comment: Note: reloading does not acknowledge changes for many of the settings in postgresql.conf (e.g. `ListenAddress`).  You need a full restart for some settings changes to take effect.

Comment: @Grzegors and @Markmann : Thanks for the answers, now I now what the limitations on administration and what I can do.